# Continuity condition for distributions in Rudin Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

On page 156 of Rudin's Functional Analysis, he gives the following condition for a linear functional over the test functions $D(\Omega)$ to be continuous:

> A linear functional $\Lambda$ on $D(\Omega)$ is continuous if and only if for each compact subset $K\subset \Omega$ there is an $N$ and a $C$ such that $|\Lambda\phi|\le C\|\phi\|_N$ for all $\phi\in D(K)$.

Here $\|\phi\|_N:=\operatorname{max}_{|\alpha|\le N, x\in\Omega}|D^{\alpha}(\phi)|$.

I am having trouble to see why continuity of $\Lambda$ implies the existence of such $C$ and $N$. In general,  for a fixed $n$, sets of the form \begin{equation}
\{\phi\in D(K):\|\phi\|_n\le 1\}
\end{equation} is not bounded in $D(K)$, right?

Can someone give a hint why the continuity condition is true?

Thanks!

Comment: Remember that $D(\Omega)$ has the final topology of the $D(K)$, so a linear functional is continuous iff it is continuous on each $D(K)$. And a functional on $D(K)$ is continuous, iff it is continuous in each seminorm $||.||_n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A distribution $\Lambda$ is continuous, iff the restriction to each $D(K)$ is continuous. Now a continuous $\Lambda$ implies for $\varepsilon = 1$ a neighbourhood $U$ in $D(K)$ represented by a seminorm $||.||_n$ and a $\delta>0$ with 
$$
U = \{\phi\in D(K); ||\phi||_n < \delta\} \,\text{and}\ |\Lambda(\phi)| < \varepsilon \,\forall\phi\in U.
$$
So for a non-zero $\phi$ set $\psi=\frac{\delta}{||\phi||_n} \phi$. Then $|\Lambda(\psi)|<\varepsilon$ and so with $C=\varepsilon/\delta = 1/\delta$
$$
|\Lambda(\phi)| = \big|\frac{||\phi||_n}{\delta} \Lambda(\psi)\big| < \frac{\varepsilon}{\delta} ||\phi||_n = C ||\phi||_n.$$